# C Language - I want to count and return the number of a specific number in an array

Tags: arrays, c

I'm a newbie to coding tests. I'm working on a problem that involves counting and returning the number of 7's in an array. But I keep getting an error, please help me understand why I am getting an error

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int solution(int array[], size_t array_len) {
int answer = 0;
for(int j=0; j<=array_len; j++){
    
    for(int i=0; array[i]<10; i++) {
        if(array[i] < 10) { 
            if(array[i] == 7) 
                answer++;
            break;
        }
        if(array[i]%10 == 7){ 
        answer++;
        }
        array[i] = array[i]/10;
        
    }
  }
return answer;
}
```

The code looks like this, and it returns 4 just fine when given an array of [7, 77, 17], and 0 just fine when given an array of [10, 29].

However, the code doesn't work at all for arrays like [777, 67].

```
test case
[7, 77, 17] return 4  - correct
[10, 29]  return 0  - correct
[777, 67] return 0  - incorrect
```

Comment: As you array contains (singed) integers...is -7 counted as 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it returns 4 just fine when given an array of [7, 77, 17] ....

It returns `4` when input array is `[7, 77, 17]` but it is just a coincidence. Try adding one more element to this array, say `7777`, which will make the number of digit `7` in array elements - `8` but the output you will get will be `5`.

Your logic to find the occurrence of number of digit `7` in array elements is wrong and having multiple problems.

Lets discuss them one by one:

**Problem - I:**

Your outer `for` loop is has extra iteration because of its condition - `j<=array_len`. Assume the array size if `3`, the loop starts from `j=0` and iterate till `j<=3` i.e. `4` times.
The loop condition should be `j<array_len`.

**Problem - II:**

Looke at inner `for` loop condition

```
array[i]<10
```

it will allow to execute the loop body only when array element is smaller than `10`. If array element is greater than `10` the loop body never executes.

**Problem III:**

In every iteration of outer `for` loop, the inner for loop starts iterating through the array from its first element and it's behaviour is like this -

- If the first element of input array is greater than or equal to `10` the nested `for` loop body will not execute.
- If the first element of input array is `7` then the nested `for` loop will count it and `break`.
- If the first element of input array is less than `10` and not equal to `7` than it will not be counted and loop will `break`.

**Problem - IV:**

Outer `for` loop condition compares `int` with `size_t`.

Above are the problems, now lets talk about solution -

First of all you don't need to iterate through whole array in nested `for` loop for every iteration of outer `for` loop. Instead, the `for` loop iterate through number of elements in array and in the body of loop, check the number of digit `7` in the current element of array under processing.

You can do:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int solution (int array[], size_t array_len) {
    int answer = 0;
    for(size_t j = 0; j < array_len; j++){
        int x = array[j];
        while (x) {
            int r = x % 10;
            if (r == 7) {
                answer++;
            }
            x = x / 10;
        }
    }
    return answer;
}

int main (void) {

    printf ("array [7, 77, 17], result : %d\n", solution ((int []) {7, 77, 17}, 3));
    printf ("array [10, 29], result : %d\n", solution ((int []) {10, 29}, 2));
    printf ("array [777, 67], result : %d\n", solution ((int []) {777, 67}, 2));
    printf ("array [7, 77, 17, 7777], result : %d\n", solution ((int []) {7, 77, 17, 7777}, 4));
    
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
array [7, 77, 17], result : 4
array [10, 29], result : 0
array [777, 67], result : 4
array [7, 77, 17, 7777], result : 8
```

Note that, this solution is not taking care of negative number, as an  input array element, containing digit `7`. Leaving it up to you to make required changes in code if array can have negative numbers in it.

Answer (score 1):

Use a more descriptive name.  Swap the order of your arguments so you can document how `array_len` and `array` are related.  Your segfault is most likely in calling code that you haven't shared with us.  Also, the logic is not correct so I rewrote the algorithm for you.

```
#include <stdio.h>

size_t count(size_t array_len, int array[array_len]) {
    size_t answer = 0;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < array_len; i++)
        for(int v = array[i]; v; v /= 10)
            if(v % 10 == 7) answer++;
    return answer;
}

int main(void) {
    struct test {
        size_t array_len;
        int *array;
        size_t expected;
    } tests[] = {
        {3, (int []) {7, 77, 17}, 4},
        {2, (int []) {10, 29}, 0},
        {2, (int []) {777, 67}, 4}
    };
    for(struct test *t = tests; t < tests + sizeof tests / sizeof *tests; t++)
        printf("%s\n", count(t->array_len, t->array) == t->expected ? "ok" : "fail");
}
```

and the output is:

```
ok
ok
ok
```

Comment: _you are accessing the array out of bounds with `j<=array_len`_ There is no array out of bound access in OP's code because `j` is never used as index of input array. But, of course, there is an extra iteration in OP's code.

Comment: Also the main signature is not valid according to the C standard.

Comment: @H.S. I should not be allowed to write on the Internet after 2am :-).   Revised answer.

Comment: @Fredrik You are correct and I revised answer, however, the compiler I use don't even generate a warning for using `main()` for `main(void)`.